# VS Code Regex Find and Replace

Tags: php, regex, visual-studio-code, regex-group

with php8 I am now getting warnings on if statements with my variables.

**Current**
`if ($var): echo $var; endif;`

**Updated Format**
`if (isset($var)): echo $var; endif;`

I am looking for a regex expression to wrap all instances of `if ($var)` and `if($var)` to `if (isset($var)`. the `$var` is not always var obviously so I think this could be accomplished with regex . Thanks!

replace: `if \(\$(.*)\)` with: `if (isset($$$1))`

This almost works but it wraps the entire *if-statement* if it begins with a `$`.

Comment: Try `\w+` instead of `.*`, to capture single words

Comment: Why would the entire `if` statement begin with `$`? You can't write `$if`. Can you show an example of the incorrect replacement?

Comment: Using \w+ worked! thanks.

Barmar - when i say the If statement begins with $ I mean inside the parentheses. ie: if ($var == 0 && $var == 3). That would be an example of ones I would not want to target